# python startswith() doesnt work on function

Tags: python

Im making a search function in python where it looks inside the CSV file and returns the similar data being searched. I am not using a CSV file and I cant seem to make the `startswith` work with it.

Here's my code:

```
def search(i):
    data = []
    name = i.capitalize()

    with open('data.csv', 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for row in reader:
            data.append(row)

    fname = [x[0] for x in data]
    
    if name in fname:
        for i in range(0, len(data)):
            if data[i][0] == name or data[i][0].startswith(name):
                return(data[i])
```

Sample Data(CSV)

```
Name1,Male,3321,name1@gmail.com
Name2,Male,1231,name2@gmail.com
Name3,Female,3421,name3@gmail.com
```

Whenever i search the full name of the person, it displays a result but not when im only searching for the first characters of the name, it doesnt work. Any help is appreciated!

Edit: What im passing through the search function is the keyword typed inside the search box

Comment: firstly share some data , also ```pandas``` can really come to your help, converting the data from csv into a dataframe.

Comment: Add some print statements in various places and try to debug.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [MRE]. Since it looks like your issue is matching data, the CSV part is likely redundant and can be replaced by hard-coded sample data.

Comment: Note that `if name in fname:` requires an exact match and cannot work for first-characters search; since it is no more efficient than the loop itself, you can just remove it. Either way, the function capitalizes the search term - it cannot match `Name1` etc.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi `'name'.capitalize()` returns `'Name'`, therefore this can work here (but can break easily).

Answer (score -1):

In `data[i][0].startswith(name)` I think it should be `name.startswith(data[i][0])`

Comment: Otherwise it wouldn't work with, for example, `'na'`, but would for `'name12'`